# How to check if the properties in a arraylist in the first index equals to a value?

Tags: java, arraylist

**Problem**

How to check if a arraylist's first value is equal to some value?
In my attempt I am trying to search in "Status" to see if it contains the values.

```
List<Employees> data = new Arraylist<Employees>();
data.add(new Employees (Status, FirstName, LastName, age));
```

**Attempt**

```
if (data.contains("Inactive")) {
    System.out.println("There are inactive Employees");
    }
else if (data.contains("{Parttime")) {
    System.out.println("There are part time Employees");
}
else {
    System.out.println("All are full time Employees");
}
```

Currently I am receiving "All are full time Employees". I am not worried about the count. If there is one inactive employee then I should be notified.

I receive the output: [Lcom.foo.Employees;@28a418. Would this cause the fault?
    System.out.println("data");

Comment: data.get(0).equals("similarity");

Comment: This is bad for so many reasons `Data.add(new Employees (Status, FirstName, LastName, age));`

Comment: @BoHalim I am still receving all "All are full time EMployees"

Comment: *"How to check if a arraylist's first value is equal to some value?"* This is not what you're trying to do. You want to check if one of the properties of the `Employees` instance on the first index equals that value. So you first need to get that instance and then act on it. Using `contains` on the list itself won't help, because it doesn't contain that searched value. Btw please decide if you like to name your list `Data` or `data`.

Comment: @Tom should I use data.equals? I want to check if Status in my Arraylist is equal to "some value"

Comment: *"I want to check if Status in my Arraylist is equal to "some value""* You can't check that directly, because you don't have an Arraylist of "Status". You have an ArrayList of Employee, so you have to check the specific Employee if it matches your expectation. Like the existing answer explains.

Comment: @Idos why is this bad? How can I improve?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you have a `List<Employee> data;`
and Employee object contain string field - status.
Try this:

```
String status = data.get(0).getStatus();
if (status != null && status.contains("Inactive")) {
    System.out.println("There are inactive Employees");
    } .....
```

Comment: It was mistake, i edited my message: data.get(0).getStatus();

Comment: If I add an else statement it would always print the else statement.